# Como abrir um Dialog sem escurecer a tela de fundo Android

Tags: java, android, view, dialog, android-activity

Tenho uma Activity, e nesta eu chamo um Dialog, porém quando abro este 'popup' a tela da Activity de fundo que o chamou escurece, mas eu gostaria que isso não acontecesse. Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: Já tentou fazer uma custom dialog? http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Answer (score 1):

Você pode setar um tema específico para a activity, assim ela não irá escurecer ao abrir qualquer Dialog:

```
<resources>
  <style name="Dialog" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

E no seu manifest, você seta esse tema para a activity que não quer que escureça ao abrir o dialog:

```
<activity android:name=".MinhaActivity" android:theme="@style/Dialog">
```

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado!